# Difference between 'Candor' and 'Sincerity'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

In the chapter 5 of the book *Creativity, Inc.* the author, Ed Catmull, writes a lot about *candor* and *honesty*, but I'm not sure I was able to fully understand what *candor* means.

Maybe I'm confused because of Portuguese (my native language). In Portuguese we have *honesty* (Honestidade), *sincerity* (Sinceridade) and *candor* (Candura). However this "equivalent" of *candor* is used **much more** for *innocence*. That's the reason I would prefer the term *sincerity*.

Is there a big difference between those two terms?

Comment: Note that "sincerity" is often used to describe the *appearance* of honesty and straight-forwardness, but may simply be a mask for deception.

Comment: A simplified version: sincerity means "If I say it, it's true", candor means "If it's true, I say it". Although sincerity can also be used to refer to statements that are false, but the speaker really believes are true.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't ever associate the word sincerity with false appearances.

Comment: @barbecue -- https://books.google.com/books?id=-QUVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22sincerity+of+an+undertaker%22&source=bl&ots=vDrPzmccRE&sig=qJEn_VyiC85oYxTq82NVyEnoNNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizmKPaoeXYAhUCCawKHXX3AB4Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22sincerity%20of%20an%20undertaker%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=yJ9zAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=%22sincerity+of+an+undertaker%22&source=bl&ots=bTPv_ET11h&sig=feiRJZuqm7y-0UnU4RS2CHAIJg4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizmKPaoeXYAhUCCawKHXX3AB4Q6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=%22sincerity%20of%20an%20undertaker%22&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks -- I believe HotLicks's example is one that involves literary implication. In the context, the expression "all the sincerity of an undertaker" is intended to mean "no sincerity at all". (The idea is that undertakers, whatever their underlying feelings, may often be trained to put on a kind of act.) I'm with barbecue on this: unless some particular literary device is in use, the meaning I would associate with 'sincerity' is that there are no false appearances although the sincere person may be mistaken etc.

Comment: @barbecue -- I'm with you on this one, see comment to HotLicks' example.

Comment: @terry-s -- But the point is that "sincerity" is often just an outward impression.

Comment: @HotLicks -- I don't believe actual 'sincerity' ever means just an outward impression: the essence of it includes real intent as well, and if the real intent is lacking then it is not sincerity at all. The meaning is shown in this respect by uses such as 'I think he was sincere about that', meaning that -- to the (fallible) extent that one can ever judge of intent by outward appearance -- this statement or behavior did look as if it was inwardly and sincerely intended.

Comment: @terry-s - So no one would ever say "He appeared sincere"?

Comment: @HotLicks -- they might say such a thng but the meaning would be that the sincerity was only being judged so far as the appearance could be taken as a reliable indicator of inward intent. If your interpretation of 'sincerity' were correct, then 'appeared sincere' would be practically repetitious and redundant, since the appearance itself, according to your expressed view, already defines and constitutes the sincerity.

Comment: "The sincerity of an undertaker" does not mean that an undertaker is sincere and that sincerity is a superficial trait. The sincerity of an undertaker means a lack of sincerity. Sincerely expressing sympathy means your expression is honest and not feigned.

Comment: One can have an appearance of sincerity which is false, but that does not change the meaning of the word sincerity, any more than a false sense of security changes the meaning of the word security.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In English, the word ***candor*** [*candour* in many dialects] has come to primarily mean openness and frankness, and a tendency to tell harsh truths.  The OED defines it as:

> Freedom from reserve in one's statements; openness, frankness, ingenuousness, outspokenness.

***Sincerity*** does mean something similar, but it doesn't generally have the "tendency to tell harsh truths" connotation.

> Freedom from dissimulation or duplicity; honesty, straightforwardness.

In other words, I would use *candor* to describe someone who speaks up about harsh truths without necessarily being asked.  *Sincerity* would describe someone who can be relied upon to tell the truth when asked, though they might not speak up on their own.  (This is why *candor* is not always viewed positively, since it can cause social friction;  whereas *sincerity* is generally seen as an unalloyed virtue.)

---

*Aside:* To my surprise, the use of *candor* to mean

> Stainlessness of character; purity, integrity, or innocence.

(which would seem to be the fashion it is used in Portuguese) can be found in older English texts, though [the OED now considers this usage "obsolete"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27009).

Comment: Sincerity does not have much to do with the content of what is said.  It has more to do with one's intentions when saying or doing something.

Comment: Interesting; although I've not seen the word used in a very long time, at least for me, it has something of a positive connotation, which doesn't jive with the "tendency to tell harsh truths" you mention. Is there a lot of variation in the meaning, or have I just learned the wrong meaning?

Comment: @errantlinguist, I think you've learned the wrong meaning. "Candid" photos, for example, are unposed pictures that might be unflattering

Comment: @JohnDoe to me, "candid" and "candour" are only vaguely related, and "candid" when applied to a person is positive as well anyway: "She's a very candid person".

Comment: @Michael Seifert I don't completely agree. Someone could be completely sincere while giving you advice you didn't ask for. And "candor" doesn't have to be harsh whatsoever. Sincere implies honesty. You'd need some type of modifier to, well, modify that: Faux sincerity. Candor implies talk which is not modified by politeness - possibly a harsh truth, but not necessarily. The type of speech used between friends could be described as candor. I'd say "candor" is open, unveiled, direct, and/or unregulated speech.

Comment: There's also a specialist legal application of 'candor' (at least in US): under a 'duty of candor', a party or lawyer has a special duty not to hold back or misrepresent anything s/he knows that is material to the subject of discussion or contention.

Answer (score 24):

'Sincerity' is being truthful in what is said; candour is the willingness to say what is truthful.

Comment: So pithy and appropriate I won't downvote, but ELU generally expects supporting evidence to accompany answers.

Comment: Very apt way of summing it up +1

Comment: Probably the strongest unctied single-sentence answer I've seen on here.

Comment: @Ross Murray Kudos, this really is one of the best answers I've ever seen! It's incomplete, and it's not always correct - but it's a great answer. I'd say replace truth with honest... And being "sincere" is only being "true" about how one "feels" about something - it doesn't imply that what one is being sincere about is actually true. And candor shouldn't be construed as, or conflated with "truth".

Answer (score 1):

In French, too, "candeur" is very strongly associated with youth. 
The word kind of presupposes that children and young people are honest because they are ignorant of the ways of the world.
So you could define "candeur" as honesty by default.
I am not quite sure that English usage really bears this out, especially modern English usage, which seems to mean, rather than direct honesty, "lack of dishonest intentions".

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved if you supplied sources  for your information. I think this a good answer if citations were supplied.

Comment: [Larousse says](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/candeur/12659) that French *candeur* is a noun meaning “le caractère d'une personne candide”, which arguably just moves the goal post as we look up what a candid person is in French. :) It’s a person “qui manifeste une grande ingénuité allant jusqu'à la crédulité,” for all that helps.

Comment: @tchrist -- The example is rather old, but one may think of the character of 'Candide' in Voltaire's work of that name. Candide seems to have been credulous enough to accept Dr Pangloss's contention, that in spite of the terrible things seen right before his eyes, 'all is for the best in this best of all possible worlds'! So yes, I suspect that in French, 'candide' probably does not mean the same as 'candid' in English.

Answer (score 0):

**Cander** — blunt no beating around the bush truthfully.

**Sincerity** — said from the heart. For you personally. No malaise intended.